# Escrever número digitado por extenso em JS

Tags: javascript, html, aplicação-web

Tenho um trabalho da faculdade para fazer onde pede para o usúario digitar um número entre 0 e 999 e o algorítimo deve imprimir o valor digitado por extenso. Pedia ajuda para a professora hoje e ele disse pra fazer usando string, onde cada número digitado fica em posição e depois o programa comparar essas valores. O probema é que não to conseguindo.

Fiz esse código abaixo só que ele não ta imprimindo os valores corretamente e está inacabado

```js
var n = (prompt("Digite um número: "));
  
  var pos_c = parseInt(n[0]); //Centena
  var pos_d = parseInt(n[0]); // Dezenas
  var pos_u = parseInt(n[0]); //Unidade
  var pos_e = parseInt(n[1]); //Especiais

  var unidades=["Zero", "Um", "Dois", "Três", "Quatro", "Cinco", "Seis", "Sete", "Oito", "Nove"];
  var especiais=["Onze", "Doze", "Treze", "Catorze", "Quinze", "Dezeseis", "Dezsete", "Dezoito", "Deznove"]; 
  var dezenas=["Dez"," Vinte", "Trinta", "Quarenta", "Cinquenta", "Sessenta", "Setenta", "Oitenta", "Noventa"];
  var centenas=["Cem", "Duzentos", "Trezentos", "Quatrocentos", "Quinhetos", "Seiscentos","Setescentos","Oitocentos", "Novecentos"];

  /*Irá verificar o tamanho vetor e em seguida fará testes para descobrir a centena,dezena e unidade do número*/

  //Imprimir unidadades
  if(n.length === 1) {
   if (n[0]== '0'||'1'||'2'||'3'||'4'||'5'||'6'||'7'||'8'||'9') {
    document.write(unidades[pos_u]);
    }
   }

  else if(n.length === 2) {
   //Números entre 20 e 99
   if(n[0]=='2'||'3'||'4'||'5'||'6'||'7'||'8'||'9' && n[1]=='1'||'2'||'3'||'4'||'5'||'6'||'7'||'8'||'9') {
    document.write(dezenas[pos_d-1]+" e "+unidades[pos_u+1]);
   }

   //Dezenas
   else if ((n[0]=='1'||'2'||'3'||'4'||'5'||'6'||'7'||'8'||'9') && n[1]==="0") {
    document.write(dezenas[pos_d-1]);
   }
   
   //Imprimir Especiais
   else if (n[0]=='1' && n[1]=='0'||'1'||'2'||'3'||'4'||'5'||'6'||'7'||'8'||'9') {
    document.write(especiais[pos_e-1]);
   }


  }
```

Tem algum outro jeito de fazer esse algorítimo?

Answer (score 1):

```js
var n = (prompt("Digite um número: "));

  var unidades=["Zero", "Um", "Dois", "Três", "Quatro", "Cinco", "Seis", "Sete", "Oito", "Nove"];
  var especiais=["Dez","Onze", "Doze", "Treze", "Catorze", "Quinze", "Dezeseis", "Dezsete", "Dezoito", "Deznove"]; 
  var dezenas=["Vinte", "Trinta", "Quarenta", "Cinquenta", "Sessenta", "Setenta", "Oitenta", "Noventa"];
  var centenas=["Cem", "Duzentos", "Trezentos", "Quatrocentos", "Quinhetos", "Seiscentos","Setescentos","Oitocentos", "Novecentos"];
  
  //Valores com 1 algarismo
  if(n.length === 1) {
   //Imprimir unidadades
   document.write(unidades[parseInt(n[0])]);
  } 

  //Valores com 2 algarismos
  else if(n.length === 2) {
   //Especiais
   if((n[0]=='1') && (n[1]=='0'||n[1]=='1'||n[1]=='2'||n[1]=='3'||n[1]=='4'||n[1]=='5'||n[1]=='6'||n[1]=='7'||n[1]=='8'||n[1]=='9')) {
    document.write(especiais[parseInt(n[1])]);
   }
   
   //Dezenas
   else if((n[0]=='2'||n[0]=='3'||n[0]=='4'||n[0]=='5'||n[0]=='6'||n[0]=='7'||n[0]=='8'||n[0]=='9') && n[1]=='0') {
    document.write(dezenas[parseInt(n[0]-2)]);
   }

   //Dezenas compostas
   else {
    document.write(dezenas[parseInt(n[0]-2)]+" e "+unidades[parseInt(n[1])]);
   }
  }

  //Valores com 3 algarimos
  else if (n.length === 3) {
   //Centenas inteiras
   if ((n[0]=='1'||n[0]=='2'||n[0]=='3'||n[0]=='4'||n[0]=='5'||n[0]=='6'||n[0]=='7'||n[0]=='8'||n[0]=='9') && (n[1]=='0' && n[2]=='0')) {
    document.write(centenas[parseInt(n[0]-1)])
   }

   //Centenas + números especiais
   else if ((n[0]=='2'||n[0]=='3'||n[0]=='4'||n[0]=='5'||n[0]=='6'||n[0]=='7'||n[0]=='8'||n[0]=='9') && (n[1]=='1') && ((n[2]=='1'||n[2]=='2'||n[2]=='3'||n[2]=='4'||n[2]=='5'||n[2]=='6'||n[2]=='7'||n[2]=='8'||n[2]=='9'))) {
    document.write(centenas[parseInt(n[0]-1)]+" e "+especiais[parseInt(n[2])])
   }

   //Centenas + Nº Compostos
   else if ((n[0]=='2'||n[0]=='3'||n[0]=='4'||n[0]=='5'||n[0]=='6'||n[0]=='7'||n[0]=='8'||n[0]=='9') && (n[1]!='1')) {
    document.write(centenas[parseInt(n[0]-1)]+" e "+dezenas[parseInt(n[1]-2)]+" e "+unidades[parseInt(n[2])]);
   }

   //Cento + Nº Especiais
   else if ((n[0]=='1') && (n[1]=='1') && (n[2]=='1'||n[2]=='2'||n[2]=='3'||n[2]=='4'||n[2]=='5'||n[2]=='6'||n[2]=='7'||n[2]=='8'||n[2]=='9')) {
    document.write("Cento e "+especiais[parseInt(n[2])])
   }

   //Cento + Nº Compostos
   else if ((n[0]=='1') && (n[1]!='1') && (n[2]!='0')) {
    document.write("Cento e "+dezenas[parseInt(n[1]-2)]+" e "+unidades[parseInt(n[2])]);
   }
  }
```

Problema resolvido,segue o codigo: